# install tensorflow-decision-forests in windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have to install tensorflow-decision-forests in windows. I tried:

```
pip install tensorflow-decision-forests
pip3 install tensorflow-decision-forests
pip3 install tensorflow_decision_forests --upgrade
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-decision-forests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-decision-forests
```

I have (pip show tensorflow):

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.9.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
```

AFIK this is the latest version amy ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tensorflow-decision-forests` 0.2.6 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-decision-forests/#files) binary wheels only for Linux and no source code. So `pip` cannot install it on non-Linux platforms.

There're [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/documentation/installation.md) on how to compile it on Linux and Mac OS X but that's all. Perhaps it's not possible to compile it anywhere else.

Comment: thanks I have seen these. may dive a go or use sagemaker (i.e. linux)

Comment: TF-DF maintainer here: Since Tensorflow no longer provides a Windows package, neither does TF-DF. Its core library, [Yggdrasil Decision Forests](https://github.com/google/yggdrasil-decision-forests) is compatible with the same models and is available on Windows